# filter by search[tags]+Unanswered+Votes

Tags: discussion, search, filtering, tag-search

I don't find a userfirendlly way to access
"All unanswered questions for the tag[bug] sorted by votes."

the target request looks like this:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/bug?tab=votes

and it is properly working... but I manually edited the URL to create it.
Is there a way to make access this type of search without cheating ?

Comment: I use "[bug] answers:0" as the search request and then click the "votes" tab so that it is sorted by votes. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks Sai works good for me, are there any other tricks like this ?

Comment: you can also type in 'votes:S' to have all questions with votes > or == S